How to setup Junit5 @Methodsources?
I'm trying to use the @MethodSources introduced in version 5.11.
Javadoc
class MapFieldsTest {
    static Stream<Arguments> testGetIntCommon() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of("a", 10),
            Arguments.of("b", 20)
        );
    }

    static Stream<Arguments> testGetIntBroken() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of("c", null),
            Arguments.of("d", null)
        );
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSources({
        @MethodSource("testGetIntCommon"),
        @MethodSource("testGetIntBroken")
    })
    void testGetInt(String givenKey, Integer expected) {
        // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testGetIntCommon")
    void testGetIntCommon(String givenKey, Integer expected) {
        // THIS WORKS
    }
    
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testGetIntBroken")
    void testGetIntBroken(String givenKey, Integer expected) {
        // THIS WORKS
    }
}

But I get an error:
MapFieldsTest.testGetInt(String, Integer) » PreconditionViolation Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest

What can be an issue with the @MethodSources setup?

Since JUnit 5.11, @MethodSource is a repeatable annotation, and @MethodSources is used as backing the container. It seems that JUnit's annotation processing doesn't check for @MethodSources but only for its nested elements. Try this instead:
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testGetIntCommon"),
@MethodSource("testGetIntBroken")
void testGetInt(String givenKey, Integer expected) {
    ...
}


Trying your solution I got an error of non-repeatable annotation. And then I figure out what was the problem. A JUnit5 version declared in my pom.xml was 5.11.3 but spring-boot-starter-test version 3.3.5 dependency was using Junit 5.10.5.
After fixing the issue with versions both solutions works now

I used this in my pom.xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.11.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

and it works fine.
BTW MethodSources is unnecessary, you can use multiple MethodSource like this
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testGetIntCommon")
    @MethodSource("testGetIntBroken")
    void testGetInt(String givenKey, Integer expected) {
        // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    }

